# How to have a c++ object with a method that takes argument the enclosing class?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to figure out if there's any known pattern/idiom in c++ for what I am trying to do here. Class A must be composed of an object that has a function whose argument must also be of type A. The following code doesn't compile since typeid may not be used in a constant expression. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct B { 
  int f(T& i) { cout << "Hello\n"; } 
};

class A {
  B<typeid(A)> b;
};

int main()
{ 
  A k;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `B<A>`? As far as I can see, there's nothing in `B` which would need a complete type.

Answer (score 1):

Your stated requirements don't need templates at all, just a forward declaration:

```
#include <iostream>

class A; // forward declare A

struct B { 
  int f(A &i); // declaration only, definition needs the complete type of A
};

class A {
  B b;
};

int B::f(A &i) { std::cout << "Hello\n"; } // define f()

int main()
{ 
  A k;
}
```

Comment: +1 D'oh. OP doesn't need template at all, at least for his stated reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `B<A> b;` The following program compiles without error or warning on g++ 4.4.3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct B {
  int f(T& i) { cout << "Hello\n"; return 0; }
};

class A {
public:
  B<A> b;
};

int main()
{
  A k;
  return k.b.f(k);
}
```

**Note**: If you are using templates only to avoid forward declaration, my solution is wrong. But, I'll leave it here in case you are using templates for some other legitimate reason.